# How to speed up function with list comprehensions?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, transformation

Is there a way to speed up or change the function to increase efficiency?

This function is needed to transform about 200.000 arrays which again consists of 2700 arrays each. Currently the process takes an eternity.

```py
def normalization(descriptors, max_value, min_value):
    if len(descriptors) == 3:
        output = []
        for descriptor in descriptors:
            output.append([[ ((feature-min_value)/(max_value-min_value)) for feature in des ] for des in descriptor])
        return np.asarray(output)
    else:
        return np.asarray([[ ((feature-min_value)/(max_value-min_value)) for feature in des ] for des in descriptors])
```

Comment: Are your arrays of the same shape? what about their content, are they the same shape too?

Comment: @Ehsan the parameter descriptor contains either an array with the shape =(2704, 128) or shape=(3, 2704, 128) The two shapes always remain the same. The contents of the arrays are of course always different. This means that the calculations are unfortunately necessary.

Comment: It looks to me like this could be faster using matrix arithmetic in numpy rather than looping via the comprehension.

Comment: BTW: you could calculate`max_value-min_value` only once before `if/else`. You could also use numpy functions (which use C/C++ code) and divide by `(max_value-min_value)` after creating numpy array. Maybe other calculations you could do also after creating array. ie, `array - min_value`

Comment: @john-mueller I am not sure if it is clear to me. So if I understand correctly, `descriptor` (which are individual elements of array `descriptors`) each consist of multiple arrays that are either of shape `(2704, 128)` or `(3, 2704, 128)`. Is this the case? And what is it exactly that you want to achieve? You still can stack those array on top of each other. You should leverage numpy array calculations. A little more explanation/sample input and output helps us better assist. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `descriptor` is a numpy array, then

```
(descriptor-min_val)/(max_val-min_val)
```

should do the job, regardless of whether it's 2D or 3D.

I think that's all your list comprehension is doing - scaling each element of the array.